# Combine method calls into one single call

Tags: php

So I have the below two methods inside my class:

```
private function set(string $id, object $set): bool
{
    return update_option('o_' . $test, $set);
}

private function save(string $id, object $r, object $set): bool
{
    return $this->set($id, $r);
}
```

Then I'm calling them as shown here:

Is it possible to call using one single method as such? `$this->save($this->set)` etc.. They're using the same $id and $set, but one has a $r added.

Comment: You already have at the end of `save_settings` - `$this->set_settings($key, $result)`, then you also want to do `set_settings('import_offices', $settings)` as well.  Are these just overwriting the values?

Comment: You're right, those seem to be overwriting it now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Conceptually, each method is replaced by its return value. But you don't want to have the return value of one function as the parameter in the other, so you cannot do that.

You can nest function calls if that is the case, for example with the following functions, which all take a string as their argument (I have made up the function names):

`uppercase(substring("Hello World!", 0, 5))`

Which would return "HELLO". Here the `substring` function returns a string, which acts as a parameter to the `uppercase` functions.

However, as you also call `set_settings` at the end of `save_settings`, the second call seems superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Oliver, looks like it's just overwriting the values now.